# Shopify APP not open in a another tab it's open in iframe

Tags: python, shopify-app, shopify-api

My app open in a iframe, I want to open it as a website like that

[image]

as like a happy return link

How can do this?

when i click on happy return then it's open a website and when i open my site it open in a iframe in shopify

I want this type of link

```
https://store.myshopify.com/admin/api_permissions/398469955819/redirect?appLoadId=454545-c155-4e20-9b5b-78454545545
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your shopify partner account.
2. Go to your created app
3. Open **App Setup**.
4. Scroll to the last
   [Embedded app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ZKg.png).
5. It will redirect to a new frame. Turn off the embedded feature and add navigation URL there.